# Pandas adding empty row below the header of csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have the following code to create csv files out of tables from a docx file:

```
from docx import Document
import pandas as pd

document = Document('my_docx.docx')

for index,table in enumerate(document.tables):
    df = [['' for i in range(len(table.columns))] for j in range(len(table.rows))]
    for i, row in enumerate(table.rows):
        for j, cell in enumerate(row.cells):
            df[i][j] = cell.text
            
        name = "tables/table_"+str(index)+".csv"
        pd.DataFrame(df).to_csv(name, index=False, header=True)
```

However, Pandas is creating an undesired empty row just below the header of the table. This only happens when `header=True`, when `header=False` this problem does not occur. But I need the header.

There's two ways I can solve this, I believe. Create the csv file with `header=True` and then delete the row or use `header=False` and then add a row to be the header. How can I do either one of these?

Comment: what do you get when you print `df.columns` just before exporting?

Comment: Print show `df.iloc[0]` and `df.columns` when `headers=True`

Comment: @teepee I get this error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'columns'

Comment: sorry I mean `pd.DataFrame(df).columns` shows what?

Comment: @RaghavGupta I get a similar error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'iloc'

Comment: @teepee printing `pd.DataFrame(df).columns`, I get: `RangeIndex(start=0, stop=2, step=1)`

Comment: It sounds like you have a blank row of data in the first row of the df... what does it look like when you print `pd.DataFrame(df).head()`?

Comment: @Mints Show the output of `print(pd.DataFrame(df).iloc[0])` just before `pd.DataFrame(df).to_csv(name, index=False, header=True)`

Comment: @teepee It prints  `0 1` header form  and  `0 1 2 3 4 ` in index form.

Comment: @RaghavGupta It prints: `0    
1    
Name: 0, dtype: object`

Comment: @RaghavGupta The docx file I'm working with has multiple tables in it. I want to create a csv file for each table on the docx.  So, one csv file per table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `df.drop(0, inplace=True)` or `df=df.iloc[1:]` to remove first row of dataframe.

So the overall code would be :-

```
from docx import Document
import pandas as pd

document = Document('my_docx.docx')

for index,table in enumerate(document.tables):
    df = [['' for i in range(len(table.columns))] for j in range(len(table.rows))]
    for i, row in enumerate(table.rows):
        for j, cell in enumerate(row.cells):
            df[i][j] = cell.text
            
        name = "tables/table_"+str(index)+".csv"
        dataFrame=pd.DataFrame(df)
        dataFrame.drop(0, inplace=True) # Or use dataFrame=dataFrame.iloc[1:]
        dataFrame.to_csv(name, index=False, header=True)
```